# Show that for $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ there is some value $x_0$ such that $f\left(x_0\right)=x_0$

Tags: calculus

Let's say I have the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ the function domain and range are $[0,1]$ and the function is continuous. Show that there is a value $x_0$ such that $f\left(x_0\right)=x_0$.

If I put the function $y=x$ on a graph I can see that this graph cut it into 2 halves and such any function that fulfil the conditions I gave has to pass through $y=x$ and that interaction point is $x_0$

How can I prove it without using graphs?

Comment: Hint: if $f(x)$ is continuous, then the function $g(x) := f(x)-x$ is also continuous. (Why?) Look at $g(0)$ and $g(1)$, and use the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $g(x)=f(x)-x$. Our goal is to prove that the function $g$ has a zero on $[0,1]$.

We know that $g(0)\ge 0$, but $g(1)\le 0$. Can you see why those two things must be true?

Now, if either value actually equals $0$, then we're done, so suppose $g(0)$ is strictly positive, and $g(1)$ strictly negative. Since $g$ is defined as the difference of two continuous functions, then it is a continuous function, and the Intermediate Value Theorem applies to it.

Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Define $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)= f(x) - x$. Prove that it is also continuous. Evaluate $g$ at $0 $ and $1$. What can you say about $g(0)$ and $g(1)$? Are they positive, negative values? How does that relate to some other famous theorem?